# jQuery datatables error in require.js: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, requirejs, datatables

Hi I'm trying to configure datables to work with require.js. I don't have a problem having it to work via regular script tags, but it fails in require.js with an error message `undefined is not function` when I attempt to initialize my datatable.

Below is my code:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min',
        'underscore': 'lib/underscore',
        'backbone': 'lib/backbone',
        'jquery.bootstrap': 'lib/bootstrap.min',
        'jquery.dataTables' : 'lib/jquery.dataTables',
        'bootstrap.datepicker' : 'lib/bootstrap-datepicker'
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'jquery.bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'bootstrap.datepicker': {
            deps: ['jquery.bootstrap']
        }
    }
});


require(['jquery', 'jquery.bootstrap','jquery.dataTables','bootstrap.datepicker'],
    function () {

        var element = {
            "roeid": "TB582552763",
            "reportDate": "20140520",
            "status": "R",
            "rejReason": "Missing Order",
            "rejType": "Context",
            "roe": "#OE#|EX|N|TB582552751|||JPMS|20140520"
        };
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            data.push(element);
        };

        var columns = [{
            sTitle: 'ROEID',
            data: 'roeid'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'Report Date',

            data: 'reportDate'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'Status',

            data: 'status'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'Rej Reason',

            data: 'rejReason'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'Rej Type',

            data: 'rejType'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'roeid',

            data: 'roe'
        }];

        $(function() {

             var oatsTable = $('#oatsTable').DataTable({
                data: data,
                columns: columns
            });


            $('#oatsTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                console.log(oatsTable.row(this).data());
                console.log(oatsTable.rows('.selected').data().length + ' row(s) selected');
            });

            $('#oats-upload-file').click(function () {
                $('#oats-file-upload-modal').modal('show');
            });

            $('#oats-file-submit').click(function () {
                $('#oats-file-upload-modal').modal('show');
            });

        });


    });
```

**UPDATE**

Since DataTables identifies itself as a named module, same way like jquery, all I had to do for this to work to use the same name as a named module, by renaming 'jquery.dataTables' dependency name to 'datables' under require.config paths, below is the working code

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min',
        'underscore': 'lib/underscore',
        'backbone': 'lib/backbone',
        'jquery.bootstrap': 'lib/bootstrap.min',
        'datatables' : 'lib/jquery.dataTables',
        'bootstrap.datepicker' : 'lib/bootstrap-datepicker'
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'jquery.bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'bootstrap.datepicker': {
            deps: ['jquery.bootstrap']
        }
    }
});


require(['jquery', 'jquery.bootstrap','datatables','bootstrap.datepicker'],
    function () {

        var element = {
            "roeid": "TB582552763",
            "reportDate": "20140520",
            "status": "R",
            "rejReason": "Missing Order",
            "rejType": "Context",
            "roe": "#OE#|EX|N|TB582552751|||JPMS|20140520"
        };
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            data.push(element);
        };

        var columns = [{
            sTitle: 'ROEID',
            data: 'roeid'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'Report Date',

            data: 'reportDate'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'Status',

            data: 'status'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'Rej Reason',

            data: 'rejReason'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'Rej Type',

            data: 'rejType'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'roeid',

            data: 'roe'
        }];

        $(function() {

             var oatsTable = $('#oatsTable').DataTable({
                data: data,
                columns: columns
            });


            $('#oatsTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                console.log(oatsTable.row(this).data());
                console.log(oatsTable.rows('.selected').data().length + ' row(s) selected');
            });

            $('#oats-upload-file').click(function () {
                $('#oats-file-upload-modal').modal('show');
            });

            $('#oats-file-submit').click(function () {
                $('#oats-file-upload-modal').modal('show');
            });

        });


    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since DataTables identifies itself as a named module, same way like jquery, all I had to do for this to work to use the same name as a named module, by renaming 'jquery.dataTables' dependency name to 'datables' under require.config paths,

below is the working code:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min',
        'underscore': 'lib/underscore',
        'backbone': 'lib/backbone',
        'jquery.bootstrap': 'lib/bootstrap.min',
        'jquery.dataTables' : 'lib/jquery.dataTables',
        'bootstrap.datepicker' : 'lib/bootstrap-datepicker'
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'jquery.bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'bootstrap.datepicker': {
            deps: ['jquery.bootstrap']
        }
    }
});


require(['jquery', 'jquery.bootstrap','jquery.dataTables','bootstrap.datepicker'],
    function () {

        var element = {
            "roeid": "TB582552763",
            "reportDate": "20140520",
            "status": "R",
            "rejReason": "Missing Order",
            "rejType": "Context",
            "roe": "#OE#|EX|N|TB582552751|||JPMS|20140520"
        };
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            data.push(element);
        };

        var columns = [{
            sTitle: 'ROEID',
            data: 'roeid'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'Report Date',

            data: 'reportDate'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'Status',

            data: 'status'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'Rej Reason',

            data: 'rejReason'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'Rej Type',

            data: 'rejType'
        }, {
            sTitle: 'roeid',

            data: 'roe'
        }];

        $(function() {

             var oatsTable = $('#oatsTable').DataTable({
                data: data,
                columns: columns
            });


            $('#oatsTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                console.log(oatsTable.row(this).data());
                console.log(oatsTable.rows('.selected').data().length + ' row(s) selected');
            });

            $('#oats-upload-file').click(function () {
                $('#oats-file-upload-modal').modal('show');
            });

            $('#oats-file-submit').click(function () {
                $('#oats-file-upload-modal').modal('show');
            });

        });


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your `shim` config:

```
'jquery.dataTables': {
    deps: ['jquery'],
    exports: 'DataTable'
}
```

The final result will be:

```
   shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'jquery.bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'bootstrap.datepicker': {
            deps: ['jquery.bootstrap']
        },
        'jquery.dataTables': {
             deps: ['jquery'],
             exports: 'DataTable'
        } 
    }
```

### What's going on?

You are attempting to run `DataTable` without previous RequireJS' consent. To have an asynchronous experience with RequireJS, you have to specify which libraries you want do dispose and how you'll call for them and that's why I exported `DataTables` through your shim configuration.

Comment: As far as I know datatables is already AMD compatible, so there is no need for shim. You solution does not change anything.

Comment: "DataTables is already AMD compatible"... So? You have to teach RequireJS with whom you want to work with. In your `$(function() { ... }`, try to check out what's the return of `DataTables`.

Comment: as per require.js you should only use shims when you module is not using define() to express your dependencies. Datatables is already doing so there is no need for this look at the first few lines of the datatables .js file.